# Conditional Execution in SSIS based on previous SQL Task output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, expression

I am currently developing a process that looks to see if a table has been updated and then add those to the offline database I am currently running from. CDC or any other form of replication is out of the question as I am not sys admin. I have some SSIS containers that I want to run based on the output of the previous SQL task etc. I am attempting to build them in expression builder and have the task output it to a variable. The variable is being populated but the type is not the same as the expression builder one. I get the following error:

> Cannot convert expression value to property type.
>   Addition information: Cannot convert 'System.String' to 'System.Boolean'

I have attempted to convert in both the expression builder and the SQL task but have had no success.

I'm sure its an easy fix but I have yet to find anything online that helps me troubleshoot this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have converted the variable to different types in the SQL task but that didn't work and I also converted it in the Expression builder but that gave a completely different error about casting parameter not valid.

This is the query that checks to see if the table exists

```
SELECT
    Case when count(*) > 0 then 1
        Else 0 end as cnt
FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] = 'Financial Information'
```

If it exists it allocated 1 else 0 to cnt. Result set is set to Single Row.

In expression builder i use:

```
@[User::cnt] = 1
```

But this throws the error:

> Cannot convert expression value to property type.
>   Addition information: Cannot convert 'System.String' to 'System.Boolean'

Comment: I assume `@[User::cnt]` is of the datatype `string`? If the Transact-SQL Task is returning 1 or 0 then why not use the `Boolean` datatype? The error is telling you the problem here, `String` and `Boolean` aren't compatible, and an expression like `@[User::cnt] = 1` will try to implicit convert the value of `@[User::cnt]` (and SSIS accepts very few implicit conversions).

Comment: I will try that tomorrow. Cheers for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is being done in a Precedence Constraint following the Execute SQL Task?  To do a comparison that returns either true or false two `=` must be used.  From the error message that you're receiving it looks like `@[User::cnt`] is a string variable.  The example below also does a comparison using a variable with the string data type, however given the query you posted I'd suggest changing this to an int data type.  If `@[User::cnt]` is changed to have have an int data type, double-quotes would then need to be removed from the expression.

[image]

Comment: @noobMan good to hear.  If my answer helped you out feel free to mark it as accepted.  There's no obligation to do this, just makes things more clear for those who may view this question in the future.